# Erlang: do list comprehension filters short circuit

Tags: erlang

Lets say I have:

```
 [ X || X<- L, some_expensive_boolean(X), some_expensive_boolean2(X)]
```

If, for any `X in L`, `some_expensive_boolean(X)` is `false`, is `some_expensive_boolean2(X)` executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: No, `some_expensive_boolean2/1` is not called.

There a couple of ways you can verify this.

#### 1. Having functions print something as they are called.

```
-module(lc).

-export([lc/1]).

lc(L) ->
  [X || X <- L, f(X), g(X)].

f(X = 2) ->
  erlang:display({f, 2}),
  false;
f(X) ->
  erlang:display({f, X}),
  true.

g(X) ->
  erlang:display({g, X}),
  true.
```

Then on the Erlang shell:

```
1> lc:lc(lists:seq(1, 4)).
{f,1}
{g,1}
{f,2} %% g is not called here
{f,3}
{g,3}
{f,4}
{g,4}
[1,3,4]
```

#### 2. Check the generated Core Erlang code.

Compiling the module with the `+to_core` option will produce a `lc.core` file with the [Core Erlang](https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/cerl/doc/core_erlang-1.0.3.pdf) code, which looks a little bit like Erlang but has its own syntax but very similar semantics.

```
erlc +to_core lc.erl
```

The code generated is quite verbose so I won't paste it here, but the gist is that there are two nested `case` expressions, one calling `f/1` with the clause that matches on `true` containing the other `case` that calls `g/1`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. It is short-circuited.

```
1> [ X || X <-[1,2], begin io:format("Test 1: ~p~n", [X]), X rem 2 =:= 0 end, io:format("Test 2: ~p~n", [X]) =:= ok ].
Test 1: 1
Test 1: 2
Test 2: 2
[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Short-circuits based on the following:

```
-module(shortcircuit).

-export([test/0]).

test() ->
  L = [1, 2, 3],
  [ X || X <- L, some_expensive_boolean(X), some_expensive_boolean2(X)].

some_expensive_boolean(X) ->
  io:format("In some_expensive_boolean: ~p~n", [X]),
  false.

some_expensive_boolean2(X) ->
  io:format("In some_expensive_boolean2: ~p~n", [X]),
  true.
```

Execute:

```
1> shortcircuit:test().
In some_expensive_boolean: 1
In some_expensive_boolean: 2
In some_expensive_boolean: 3
[]
2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create an example:

```
$ cat test.erl
-module(test).

-export([show/0]).

show() ->
   [ X || X <- [1,2,3,4,5], bigger(X), smaller(X)].

bigger(X) ->
   io:format("bigger ~p~n", [X]),
   X > 2.

smaller(X) ->
   io:format("smaller ~p~n", [X]),
   X < 4.
```

and test it:

```
14> c(test).
{ok,test}
15> test:show().
bigger 1
bigger 2
bigger 3
smaller 3
bigger 4
smaller 4
bigger 5
smaller 5
[3]
```

So the answer is: NO.